# What is the penalty for a Hiruma Slayer wielding an off-hand Masakari?

Tags: l5r, l5r-4e

The Hiruma Slayers alternate path (from The Book of Earth) has the following line in it's technique:

> You suffer no penalties
>   for using a masakari in your off-hand (although you still
>   suffer normal penalties for wielding two weapons).

The L5R 4th Edition Core rulebook has the following text about dual wielding:

> A character’s handedness is determined by the
>   player. A character attempting to make an attack
>   with a weapon in his off-hand suffers a penalty of -5
>   to the roll if it is a small weapon, -10 if it is medium,
>   and -15 if it is large. Additionally, attacks made with
>   the character’s dominant hand suffer a penalty of
>   -5 to attacks as long as a secondary weapon is held
>   in the off hand. However, a character wielding two
>   weapons is more difficult to hit due to the larger area
>   covered. As a result, characters wielding two weapons
>   add their Insight Rank to their Armor TN.

So what does this mean for the Hiruma Slayer? Does he:

1. Have a -5 to his attacks with his primary hand, and no penalty for attacks with his off-hand?
2. Have no penalty to his attacks with his primary hand, and a -15 to attacks with his off-hand?
3. Have a -5 to his attacks, regardless of which hand he's using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Have a -5 to his attacks with his primary hand, and no penalty for attacks with his off-hand

The Masakari is a medium weapon. This means that if we dual wield with it in our offhand, the character suffers a -5 penalty for his main hand and -10 penalty for his offhand. If the character looses / drops the Masakari, all penalties are removed (Off-hand weapons & Multiple Attacks p141).

The alternate path of the Hiruma Slayers cancels out the offhand penalty. This would result in the character only suffering a -5 penalty for the main hand as long as he's holding the Masakari.

Comment: whoops. I thought it was a large weapon. Great catch on that! Seems like eliminating the off-hand penalty only would just make the player make all of his attacks with his off-hand instead of his primary hand, which strikes me as strange...

Comment: But the RAI is clearly meant to enhance the savage dual-wielding berserker feeling. By only attacking with the offhand, the player is trying to circumvent that with a very strict RAW interpretation. In that case he's no longer dual-wielding, but strictly attacking with his offhand. Enough cause to reinstate the -10 penalty.